# Finishing Keno Java code?

Tags: java

This is what I am having trouble with. I am making a Keno game out of a Crystals code I was given. So far, I have been able to choose 20 of the 80 and turn them red. However, I have the button set to when I press it it says "Game is a draw" and the window closes.

I am trying to put in a code where it will randomly draw 20 numbers without repeating, and then they turn yellow, however, if the CPU and the human match a number, it will turn green. I have no idea how to start this code or how to go about doing it. Here is what I have:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class Kenogame {

  // constants
  public static final int WIDTH = 4;
  public static final int HEIGHT = 20;
  public static final int INITIAL = 0;
  public static final int RED = 1;
  public static final int YELLOW = 3;
  public static final int CHECKED = 4;

  private int turn = RED; // to track which player should play next

  private int[][] playerGrid; // to record each player's move
  private int[][] shadowGrid; // to keep track of which atoms have been FOUND
  private int[][] crystalGrid; // to extract a single crystal from playerGrid

  private int row, column; // position of most recently added atom
  private int lowX, lowY, highX, highY; // corner coordinates of current crystal
  private int player1Score = 0;
  private int player2Score = 0;

  // GUI related fields
  private JButton[] buttonArray;
  // private JTextField scoreField1;
  // private JTextField scoreField2;
  // private JLabel labelRED;           // Label "Red" on GUI
  // private JLabel labelYELLOW;    // Label "Yellow" on GUI
  private JLabel labelTurn; // Label displays whose turn is next
  private int numberToSelect = 20;
  Kenogame() {
    createGUIAndPlay();
  }

  private void createGUIAndPlay() {
    final JFrame f = new JFrame();
    // create the panels
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();

    // represents the 2D grid of buttons on the GUI
    buttonArray = new JButton[WIDTH * HEIGHT];


    // stores the positions of atoms in both player's crystals
    playerGrid = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    // shadowGrid keeps track of which atoms have been found 
    shadowGrid = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    // used to store a crystal to determine if it is a perfect crystal
    crystalGrid = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT];


    JButton endGameButton = new JButton("Start Draw");
    // labelRED = new JLabel("Red");

    // scoreField1 = new JTextField(3);
    // scoreField1.setEditable(false);
    //labelYELLOW = new JLabel("Yellow");
    labelTurn = new JLabel(Integer.toString(numberToSelect), Label.LEFT);
    Dimension dim = labelTurn.getPreferredSize();
    labelTurn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(dim.width + 100, dim.height + 10));
    // scoreField2 = new JTextField(3);
    // scoreField2.setEditable(false);
    // scoreField1.setText("0");
    // scoreField2.setText("0");

    // create the buttons on which players will make their moves
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT * WIDTH; i++) {

      buttonArray[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
      buttonPanel.add(buttonArray[i]);
    }
    final Color buttColor = buttonArray[0].getBackground();
    // add the action listener to the buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT * WIDTH; i++) {
      buttonArray[i].setActionCommand(Integer.toString(i));
      buttonArray[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
          if (button.getBackground() == Color.RED) {
            button.setBackground(buttColor);
            numberToSelect++;
          } else {
            if (numberToSelect > 0) {
              button.setBackground(Color.RED);
              numberToSelect--;
            }
          }
          //    button.setEnabled(false);
          int buttonIndex = Integer.valueOf(button.getActionCommand());
          row = buttonIndex / WIDTH;
          column = buttonIndex % WIDTH;
          // playMove();

          labelTurn.setText(Integer.toString(numberToSelect));
          // updateGUI();
        }
      });
    }

    endGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s;
        //  Need to add "ball draw here" for Keno 
        //  20 random numbers between 1 and 80

        // each time a "ball" matches one selected on the Keno ticket add to a counter
        // at end look up payout for the number of matches corresponding to the counter
        if (player1Score > player2Score)
          s = "RED wins the game";
        else if (player1Score < player2Score)
          s = "YELLOW wins the game";
        else
          s = "Game is a draw";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, s, "Game Over", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
      }
    });

    labelPanel.add(endGameButton);
    labelPanel.add(labelTurn);
    topPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    topPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(topPanel);
    f.setSize(1000, 400);
    f.setTitle("Keno");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  private void playMove() {
    playerGrid[row][column] = turn;
    if (turn == RED) {
      turn = YELLOW;
    } else {
      turn = RED;
    }
  }

  private void initialize() {
    highX = highY = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    lowX = lowY = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++)
      for (int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++) {
        crystalGrid[row][column] = INITIAL;
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Keno();
  }
}

// green for a match, yellow for a no-match.
```

I have 4 lines towards the bottom where I am supposed to insert the code. I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hand on this.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? Did you do the 20-number non-repeating draw yet?

Comment: I believe what your tutor meant, use internet resources such as Java Documentation and the only two components that you need to understand in your assignment are randomization and array comparison. This question is voted down so much because Stack Overflow community isn't supposed to do your homework for you. You show no understanding of the problem, and no attempt of solving it by yourself. Be careful with posting questions like these as it can lead to plagiarism, and I'm pretty sure your tutor is more than capable of finding out who plagiarised.

Answer (score 2):

To draw 20 non-repeating numbers, you can do the following:

1. put your 80 numbers in a collection.
2. shuffle the collection
3. the elements are now in random order and you can loop over the collection to get the first 20 elements.

If you give me more details on what you are stuck, I can provide further information.

Comment: @JohnClark Do you know what a collection is? Do you know what the `Collections` API is (and that it has a `shuffle` function)? I mean, SO isn't really going to do your homework--we require proven effort.